# Is there a Chrome app that works like scratchpad in Firefox?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am looking for a Chrome extension or app that works similar to scratchpad in Firefox where I can code and test Javascript!

Comment: This doth not belongeth on SO. This question should be closed as "off-topic".

Comment: @GordonFreeman any what you linked to is NOTHING like what the poster asked for.

Comment: Oopsie! Maybe my answer will fair better... :)

Comment: You can download [javascript-scratchpad-chrome](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-scratchpad-chrome/), which is almost identical in functionality. After downloading, in Chrome, type `chrome://extensions/` in the address bar, and ensure `Developer mode` is checked. Click `Load unpacked extension...` and select the downloaded folder. You will now have a scratchpad.

Answer (score -16, accepted):

Chrome Developer Tools. It's a set of tools... for developers... It's installed by default, but you can add further functionality to it. In this case, you don't have to install anything...

Take a look: [Chrome Developer Tools - Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: It is not even nearly comparable. Scratchpad in Firefox more like live JS editor not live console.

Comment: check this link https://code.google.com/p/javascript-scratchpad-chrome/ .It is still in development i guess.

Comment: Check this link instead: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en#create-snippet, or search for Chrome Snippets, it's the same thing as Firefox's Scratchpad.